# Google Play Games profile fails to change my game profile to public

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, profiles, google-play-games

I've been experiencing a problem with the 'Play Games' app from Google on my tablet.

When I go to my profile, I see a message showing me

> Your Game Profile is hidden
>   Touch to change this setting

[image: SCREENSHOT]

In order to make it public, I touch the option, 
and press the <kbd>Make Public</kbd> button. Then, I see a popup saying that my profile is being updated and then a toast appears telling that my profile has been updated.

However, when I go back and re-visit my profile, the message still persists meaning that my profile is *still* hidden.

Also, my friend told me that he can't see me in his 'Players' list even though he follows me on Google+. This means that my profile is not public.

So, **How do I make my profile public?**

My tablet is running Android Kitkat 4.4.2 and has all the apps (Including Google Play Games) updated.

Comment: My Google Play App is now the latest version and now I'm not facing this problem.

Comment: Sounds like a permission issue, where unless you have root it reverts regardless of what you have set

Answer (score 1):

In the `About me` section of your google profile is where you can make your profile public or private.